# Link_to not returning extra parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this link with the extra "context" parameter:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t(:task_delete), task, :context => 'homepage', :class => 'delete_link', :remote => :true, :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t(:sure) %>
```

When in the controller, how do I read this parameter, it should be "params[:context] right?
When I do this in the controller, it returns nothing:

```
logger.debug "CONTEXT "+params[:context]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it would be in params[:context], if you added it to the link this way:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t(:task_delete), task_path(task, :context => 'homepage'), 
            :class => 'delete_link', :remote => :true, 
            :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t(:sure) %>
```

as it has to be a part of the path